# Remove the css of a child class by a parent class

Tags: css

I have

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="child">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.child{  width:2px;height:3px };
.parent .child{color:blue};
```

I want to remove the style of child class when I include the parent in the css ie if I use .parent .child there should not be width and height style to child ie the style of child should be removed if used along with parent.How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code snippet will work. When the child is inside the parent node, set it's width and height to the element default, which is `auto`.

```
.parent .child {
    color: blue;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: or use `.parent > .child {}` if you only want to select .child classes directly under a .parent